# JavaScript - Hide an element when another element is fully inside the viewport

Tags: javascript

I want to hide .isi-jumo-link when .indication is fully visible in the viewport. Currently it only disappears once .indication is at the top of the viewport.

User needs to scroll from the top and once .indication is fully in view then .isi-jump-link will disappear.

```
$(window).on('scroll', function () {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() >= $('.indication').offset().top) {
        $('.isi-jump-link').hide();        
    }
    else {
        $('.isi-jump-link').show();
    }
});
```

Just to note... using a fixed scrollTop in my case will not work.

Answer (score 0):

You could check if the both the top and the bottom of your indication is within the viewport:

```
$(window).on('scroll', function () {
    var bottomIsVisible = $(this).scrollTop() + $(this).height() >= $('.indication').offset().top + $('.indication').height();
    var topIsVisible = var topIsVisible = $(this).scrollTop() <= $('.indication').offset().top;
    if (bottomIsVisible && topIsVisible) {
        $('.isi-jump-link').hide();        
    }
    else {
        $('.isi-jump-link').show();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the height of the `.indication` `<div>` also to the equation:

```
$(window).on('scroll', function () {
  if ($(this).scrollTop() >= ($('.indication').offset().top + $('.indication).height())) {
    $('.isi-jump-link').hide();        
  }
  else {
    $('.isi-jump-link').show();
  }
});
```